# R: how to get dummy variables only for top levels of a categorical variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data, janitor

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
data <- data_frame(var = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE))

   > data
# A tibble: 20 × 1
     var
   <chr>
1      A
2      A
3      B
4      A
5      B
6      B
7      C
8      B
9      B
10     A
11     B
12     C
13     A
14     B
15     C
16     C
17     A
18     B
19     B
20     C
```

I would like to create **dummy variables** corresponding to each level of `var`, but there is a catch: 
I  want to restrict the creation of dummies **only** to the top `n` levels of `var`. The reason for that is simple: in my dataset there are thousands and thousands of different levels for `var`.

That is, if `n = 2` here, it will  create dummies only for `B` and `A`, as shown in the frequency table below.

```
> janitor::tabyl(data,var , sort = TRUE)
  var n percent
1   B 9    0.45
2   A 6    0.30
3   C 5    0.25
```

How can I do that in the most concise way possible? Output is, as usual, something like

```
dummy_B   dummy_A
0         1
0         1
1         0
0         1
```

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to set a seed and add library calls

Comment: done amigo. thanks for your help!

Comment: where do you get `tabyl`

Comment: `var <- c('A','B'); data[, paste0('dummy_', var)] <- lapply(var, function(x) +(data$var == x)); data`

Comment: @rawr it's from `tibble` and/or `janitor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read about your Big Data issue, here's my revised solution:

```
n     <- 2    # set your n here
data1 <- data # I just did this step for testing; it's totally optional
data1$var[! data1$var %in% tabyl(data,var , sort = TRUE)$var[1:n]] <- NA

booya           <- model.matrix(~var-1, data1)
head(booya)
```

> ```
>   varA varB
> 1    0    1
> 4    1    0
> 5    1    0
> 6    1    0
> 7    0    1
> 8    1    0
> ```

Note that you don't need to create an extra copy of the data object; I just did that for my own purposes. If you don't want to mess up the original `var` column you could just create a new column or character vector.

This was my original attempt, which is not good for big data:

```
n <- 2 # set your n here

tmp           <- model.matrix(~var-1, data)
colnames(tmp) <- gsub("^[[:alpha:]]", "", colnames(tmp))
colnames(tmp) <- gsub("^[[:alpha:]]", "", colnames(tmp))
colnames(tmp) <- gsub("^[[:alpha:]]", "", colnames(tmp))
final         <- tmp[, colnames(tmp)%in%tabyl(data,var , sort = TRUE)$var[1:n]]

head(final)
```

> ```
>   A B
> 1 0 1
> 2 0 0
> 3 0 0
> 4 1 0
> 5 1 0
> 6 1 0
> ```

Comment: thanks @hack-r ! but are nt we getting the same problems as above with `model.matrix` ? too big a matrix here

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
set.seed(100)
data <- data_frame(var = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE))

# Number of levels
n <- 2
bind_cols(
  data, 
  data %>% 
    group_by(var) %>% 
    summarise(total=n()) %>%
    top_n(n, total) %>% 
    select(var) %>% `[[`(1) %>%
    sapply(function(x) (data$var == x) * 1) %>%
    as_data_frame())

# data %>% `[[`(1) is equal to data[[1]]
```

Comment: thanks @jasonwang but I am lost at    `select(var) %>% `[[`(1) %>%
    sapply(function(x) (data$var == x) * 1) %>%` can you just explain what your doing here?

Comment: I changed from `data.frame` to vector for `sapply`. "`[[`" is the select operator. "`[[`(1)" selects the first column in the `data.frame`.

Comment: Basically it's `data[[1]]`. Just updated in the answer because it's messy in the comment.

Comment: thanks and sorry for my noobiness but what is the purpose of the one in ` (data$var == x) * 1` ?

Comment: `data$var == x` is a boolean vector, so I used `*1` to change it into numeric, which might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

Thinking about the big data aspect, you could define a function to do this. May not be very efficient, but will only return the number of columns required.

```
model_matrix <- function(variable, data, numlevels, end = TRUE) {
  tmp <- table(data[variable])
  if(end) {
    lvl <- unlist(attr(tmp, 'dimnames'))[(length(tmp)-numlevels+1):length(tmp)]
  } else {
    lvl <- unlist(attr(tmp, 'dimnames'))[1:numlevels]
  }  
  mat <- data.frame(do.call("cbind", 
      lapply(seq_along(lvl), function(xx) ifelse(data[variable] == lvl[xx], 1, 0))
  ))
  names(mat) <- paste0('var', lvl)
  mat
}
```

Now you can run:

```
library(tibble)
set.seed(100)
data <- data_frame(var = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE))
model_matrix('var', data, 2, end = TRUE)
```

The benefit of this approach is it should generalize to more variables as follows

```
data <- data_frame(var = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                   var2 = sample(c('D', 'E', 'F'), 20, replace = TRUE))
vars <- c('var', 'var2')
lapply(vars, model_matrix, data = data, numlevels = 2)
```

### Old Answer

I would use `model.matrix` and then select the columns you want directly.

```
library(tibble)
set.seed(100)
data <- data_frame(var = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE))

model.matrix(~var, data)
```

Comment: thanks but thats the problem. I dont want to create these unnecessary dummy variables. I am talking about thousands of different levels here (even more)

Comment: that model matrix is going to crash my computer

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be sort of a hack,

```
dummy_top_n <- function(data_frame, column, n){
  order_vec <- vector()
  for ( i in 0:(n-1)){
    order_vec <- c(order_vec,names(sort(table(data_frame[,column]),
             partial=length(table(data_frame[,column])) - i )[length(table(data_frame[,column])) - i ]))
  }
  colnames(data_frame)[which(colnames(data_frame) == column)] <- 'dummy_'
  dummies <- model.matrix(~ dummy_ - 1, data=data_frame)
  return(dummies[,rev(which(names(table(data_frame)) %in% order_vec ))])
}

dummy_top_n(data, 'var',2)
```